# Why Intel® HAXM installation failed, when installing Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to install android studio. Then a Dependency Intel® HAXM installing and the installation is failed. I don't know why. I try a lot of solutions. I don't have Hyper-V! (unchecked). SDK is up to date also Android Studio is up to date.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoYN6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find [here](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/android-studio/haxm-installation-failed-install-intel-haxm-in-windows/) a detailed article with all the possible solutions you can try for this specific error.

Every solution shown has each step it needs in detail with appropriate screenshots.

All other threads in stackoverflow about this same error you have, suggest one of the solutions that are listed on the aforementioned link. So, if you try them one by one, I'm sure one of them will resolve your error.